# проблема с кодировкой в swing

Tags: java, swing, charset

есть такой код:

```
private JTextPane htmlTextPane = new JTextPane();
htmlTextPane.setContentType("text/html;Charset=CP1251");
```

при выводе содержания поля htmlTextPane с помощью getText() вместо русских символов выводятся html коды символов вида &#nnnn;
что нужно сделать, чтоб вместо этого нормально выводились русские символы?

Answer (score 0):

```
package Test;

import javax.swing.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String  arg[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setBounds(0,0,100,100);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextPane htmlTextPane = new JTextPane();
        htmlTextPane.setContentType("text/html;Charset=CP1251");
        frame.add(htmlTextPane);
        htmlTextPane.setVisible(true);
        htmlTextPane.setText("asd100023");
        System.out.println(htmlTextPane.getText());
    }
}
```

Вывод. Что не так?

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    asd100023
  </body>
</html>
```